# How to change separator character between name and number?

Tags: interface, workflow

For now when I make a copy of some object - Blender numerate this object by pasting dot as a separator between name and number.

I want it to numerate with " _ " as separator before number.

Anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to change this behavior natively. However, you can simply rename your objects in bulk.

I personally like to use [name panel addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-7). In this case, you could use *batch name* option, and replace `.` with `_`.

Before renaming:

[image]

Outliner after:

[image]